# Best way to specify a configuration for docker-wrapped application

Tags: docker

I want to containerize my application using docker, and I was wondering - what's the best way to specify configuration for each container. I need to run the same software in a few configurations. **Config file**, **ENVs**, **CLI arguments**?

Right now, the application is using a **YAML** file as config. Any suggestions to make configuration better and less painful?

*Spoiler: I'm a docker newbie*